# Installing software via Lutris

Tags: wine

I'm rather confused about what I'm supposed to do with software to install through Lutris. Using Wine directly is more or less straighforward, and can be done easily through the terminal, or graphically. Lutris however, just has installer scripts that set up the environment that works for particular software.

Lutris has an option to manually add software already installed, where you can set the main executable file, but this doesn't help, as the software is not installed at this stage.

So if I have a disc, USB drive, or ISO that has been mounted, how am I meant to run the actual installer that installs the software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply find the Lutris installer script which is labelled with `DVD version`, `CD version` or something similar for your game here: [Lutris Game DB](https://lutris.net/games/)

Assuming the required wine libraries provided by your distro maintainer are installed, upon clicking the `lutris:` link, the Lutris software should walk you through the installation process.

After this is complete, the game should be available from the Lutris Wine runners list, as the script will have created a runner for you.

If you cannot find your game, consider an alternative software such as PlayOnLinux.

Comment: Does that mean that the only software to work via Lutris is what's in the database? There's no manual installation? If so, I guess I'll just keep trying my luck directly through Wine.

Comment: If your game is not on that list, Lutris can't help you. It is an extensive list of over 6000 games, so that's unfortunate. A manual installation option is available for after you've installed the application normally by running the installer through Wine from the disk, but it can't bring you any performance enhancements. Wine should be able to get through the installation process itself. If you need performace enhancements, turn to PlayOnLinux, they have broader game support.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue; unable to use games/software unless there was an install script for it. And even then, it was hit and miss. Installing games manually through Lutris is very simple once you've done it once or twice. I found this guide here and I've been running games ever since:
https://forums.lutris.net/t/very-brief-tutorial-on-manually-installing-a-game-in-lutris/2028

Hope it helps!

Comment: You should quote and cite the relevant information from that external resource.  Answers within their body should answer the question, it shouldn't be necessary to go to another website.